# I cannot pass data to view it show http error 500 in laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi guyz i am kind of new to laravel and im trying to show the reviews posted by users . Now i checked with dd() and indeed i am able to get that data however when i send it to the view laravel responds with Http error 500. Previously i was only sending the doctors data which was working fine but when i tried to pass the reviews this happened.
This is my show Profile function

```
     public function profile($id)
    {
    $doctor=Doctor::find($id);
    $reviews=Review::where('doctor_id',$doctor->account_id)->get();

   // dd($doctor,$reviews);
    //  foreach($reviews as $review)
    //  {
    //      dd($doctor,$review);
    //  }
   // dd($reviews);
   // dd(DB::select("select * from reviews where doctor_id='D-1'"));
    //dd(Review::all()->where('doctor_id',$doctor->account_id));
   // $reviews=;
  // $array=['reviews'=>$reviews];
    return View('pages.doctorProfile',['reviews'=>$reviews])->with('doctor',$doctor);
}
```

and this is the section of the view where i was trying to show the review

```
@foreach($reviews as $review)
    <!-- Comment List -->
    <li>
    <div class="comment">
        <img class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle" alt="User Image" src="/storage/images/patients/{{$review->patient->image}}">
        <div class="comment-body">
            <div class="meta-data">
                <span class="comment-author">{{$review->patient->first_name}} {{$review->patient->last_name}}</span>
                <span class="comment-date">{{$review->created_at}}</span>

            </div>
            <div  class="review-count rating">
                <?php $rating=explode('-',$review->rating)  ?>
                @for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
                    @for($i=1;$i<=$rating[1];$i++)
                        <i class="fas fa-star filled"></i>
                    @endfor
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                @endfor
                {{-- <i class="fas fa-star filled"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star filled"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star filled"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star filled"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i> --}}
            </div>
            <p class="comment-content">
               {{$review->content}}
            </p>
            <div class="comment-reply">
                <a class="comment-btn" href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-reply"></i> Reply
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <!-- /Comment List -->
@endforeach
```

Need this solved quick. Please help

Comment: Can you turn on APP_DEBUG in your .env file to view exact error?

Comment: Check to inspect element and network tab to catch more details about error then share with me pls,

Comment: Try this return View('pages.doctorProfile', compact('reviews', 'doctor'));

Comment: I am now using return View('pages.doctorProfile',compact('reviews',$reviews))->with('doctor',$doctor);

this code is working for one doctor  record but not the other

Comment: my App_debug is already set to true 

i dont know what to look for in the networking tab

Comment: 1) Your Laravel, web server and PHP logs will tell you exactly what the problem is. 2)  [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

I see several things here, the code should be like this:

```
$doctor=Doctor::find($id);
$reviews=Review::where('doctor_id',$doctor->account_id)->with('patient')->get();
return view('pages.doctorProfile',['reviews'=>$reviews]);
```

I don't see anything strange in the view, check if changing that makes the work.

Comment: Okay so a strange thing happened i changed the code back to compact('reviews',$reviews) which previously wasnt working and well it started working again but now if i try to view the review for some other doctor it is giving me 500 error again

Comment: What do you mean by trying to view the review? is another route or in the same view? and how you trying to show the review?

Comment: I mean i have a page with  2 sections the doctor details ,and the review details. when i click on a button it goes to that profile function and displays doctor's profile page. Now the problem is that my code is working  for Doctor-1 but for Doctor-2 it responds with error 500

Comment: Ups, maybe you are trying to echo a null value? try to change app_debug to true in the .env file, to see the detailed error ;)

Comment: i  thought i was echoing a null value but i checked it with the dd() method to see if i was actually passing the data and well its not a null value i checked it that data is indeed there in the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass both $reviews and $doctor into view, you can do it like this :

```
public function profile($id){
    $data = ['reviews'=>null,'doctor'=>null];
    $doctor = Doctor::find($id);
    $reviews = Review::where('doctor_id',$doctor->account_id)->get();
    $data = ['reviews'=>$reviews,'doctor'=>$doctor];
    return view('pages.doctorProfile',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
     @for($j=1;$j<=$rating[1];$j++)
          <i class="fas fa-star filled"></i>
     @endfor
     <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
@endfor
```

change i to j, becouse execute infinite time

I think you are considering

```
 @for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    <i class="fas fa-star {{ $i<= $rating[1] ? 'failed' : '' }}"></i>
 @endfor
```